# Is it possible to calculate the Count of text fields in a column in power bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

```
2024 Customer = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Group]),TREATAS({2024},Table1[Year]))
Lost 2024 = IF([2024 Customer]=0,"LOST")
```

[image]

I used the above measures to display lost customers as "LOST" in the table, I need to get the Count of "LOST". Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Please paste sample data in markdown format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking how to count rows of a Measure value.

Try:

```
Lost count =
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT(Table1[Group]), 
    IF([Lost 2024] = "LOST", 1)
 )
```